# Do different software programs store meta keyword tags differently?

Tags: software, metadata, tagging

I run a popular sports photography site, and allow photographers to upload photos and then tag them to make it easier for the competitors to find their individual photos.

Some photographers find it beneficial to tag their photos before uploading them, and then have to re-tag them once uploaded.

In these instances I'd like to programmatically read the tags from the JPEG files when they're uploaded.

On one sample file I've been sent the tags are stored in iptc > APP13 > 2#025.

Is that pretty much always the case, or do different programs store them in different fields?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hope you don't mind I changed the title. I saw initially and thought what is this going to be (wasn't particularly clear), but it's a genuingly fair question! (Just in case of DV based on title alone)

Comment: I think there's perhaps a bit more to the question as well, related to not just keywords.  For example, people might tag them with captions, titles, labels, keywords... there's a ton of possibilities and choices. These are not so much technical implementation differences as choices made by the photographer.  And on top of field choice, there's format, for keywords hierarchical or not, etc.

Comment: Are you writing a program for your site that processes the raw EXIF data from the file, or are you planning to use a third-party library like [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to extract the data?

Comment: Currently I do it with bare php myself, but I'll look into the tool to see if it helps in any way

Answer (score 1):

JPEG, TIFF, PSD, and other file formats can include numerous types of standards, so as long as your software can be written to detect and parse these standards, you should be able to extract the information you need.

Some of the standards that programs use to store meta data on images include:

- Exif
- XMP
- IPTC-IIM
- IPTC Core & Extension
- PLUS
- Dublin Core

There are others as well.